# Choose diagonal matrix $D$ to make $DB$ as orthonormal as possible

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, approximation, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $B\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $m>n$. How can I choose $d_1,\dots,d_m$ such that $DB$, with $D_{ij} = d_i \delta_{ij}$, $1\leq i,j\leq m$, is not far from orthonormal, i.e., $\|B^{T}D^{T}DB-\text{Id}\|$ is small?

For some choices of matrix norm, the minimizer can maybe worked out using  a singular value decomposition. I haven't succeeded in this, but I am more interested in a cheap solution anyway, even if it does not provide the exact minimum. Hence, I also do not care to specify the exact matrix norm.

Answer (score 1):

We can recast minimizing $\Vert B^TD^TDB - I\Vert_F$ as a constrained least squares problem of the form $\min_x \Vert f-Ax\Vert_2$, $x\geq 0$ so that it can be solved with any standard non-negative least squares software package. I'm sure there are better solutions than this, but it seems to work reasonably well in practice.

Note that,
$$
(B^TD^TDB)_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^{m} d_k^2 b_{k,i}b_{k,j}
$$

Thus, let $x$ be the $m\times 1$ vector with $k$-th entry $d_k^2$ and let $A$ be the $n^2\times k$ matrix with rows of the form,
$$
A_{\ell,:} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1,i}b_{i,j} & b_{2,i}b_{2,j} & \cdots & b_{m,i}b_{m,j}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\ell = (i-1)\cdot n + j$ and $i,j=1,\ldots,n$.

Finally set $f$ to be the $n^2\times 1$ vector where the $\ell$ entry is one if $i=j$ and 0 otherwise; i.e. 1 when $\ell = 1, n+2, \ldots, (n-1)\cdot n+n=n^2$ and 0 otherwise.

Then,
$$
\Vert f - Ax \Vert_2^2 = \sum_{i=j} \left( \sum_{k=1}^m d_k^2 b_{k,i}^2 - 1 \right)^2 + \left(\sum_{i\neq j} d_k^2 b_{k,i}b_{k,j}\right)^2
= \Vert B^TD^TDB - I\Vert_F^2 
$$

Here is a numpy implementation which seems to work reasonably well.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy import optimize

m,n = 100,10
B = np.random.randn(m,n) # generate random test matrix B

i = np.repeat(np.arange(n),n) 
j = np.tile(np.arange(n),n)

A = B.T[i]*B.T[j] # rows are pointwise product of all pairs of rows of B
f = (i==j) # set f = 1 if i=j and 0 otherwise

x,_ = sp.optimize.nnls(A,f)
D = np.diag(np.sqrt(x))

print(np.linalg.norm(f-A@x))
print(np.linalg.norm(B.T@D.T@D@B-np.eye(n)))
```

EDIT: I misread the original problem as picking $B$ given $D$.

<strike>Suppose $B$ is also diagonal. Then $DB$ is diagonal with entry $d_ib_i$ in the $i,i$ position. Thus, choosing $b_i = 1/d_i$ gives the first $n$ columns of the $m\times m$ identity so that $(DB)^T(DB) = I_n$.</strike>

Did you by chance mean when $n>m$?

Comment: I don't understand, is there a connection between your solution in the special case and your assumption that I might have meant $n>m$? (I didn't)

Comment: There are many exact solutions $B$ so that $B^TD^TDB = I$ when $m>n$, however there might not always be an exact solution when $n>m$ so that seemed like the more interesting case to me.

Comment: If there are many, all the better. I just need one though, maybe one of the many is easy to find, even in the case of general $B$?

Comment: Oh sorry, I completely misread your question and thought you were starting with $D$ and wanted to pick $B$. My fault.

Comment: Because, as you've calculated, the matrix entries depend only linearly on $d_k^2$, the $L^1$- and $L^\infty$-norm optimization problems can also be solved by writing them as linear programs.